# max_input_time= -1 What is the exact meaning of -1?

Tags: php, php-ini

I couldn't find this in the docs, but does:

```
max_input_time = -1
```

means there is no limit?

I find it odd that `max_execution_time = 0` is forever.

But what does `-1` mean for `max_input_time` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick look into the `php.ini` file will show you:

```
; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time=60
```

So as you already guessed correct:

```
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can see the `php.ini` files for production and development on [github](https://github.com/php/php-src):

- [`php.ini` file for production](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production#L370)
- [`php.ini` file for development](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-development#L370)

Comment: Is "-1" valid for all versions of PHP?

Comment: @luisdev Don't know it exactly, but I'm pretty sure it's for every PHP version.

Answer (score 10):

Actually the documentation says it different:

> **max_input_time** integer
>
> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. Timing begins at the moment PHP is  invoked at the server and ends when execution begins. **The default setting is -1, which means that max_execution_time is used instead.** Set to 0 to allow unlimited time.

The doc is here:
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time

So, to my understanding the comment provided in php.ini is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` you will find the answer to your question:

```
; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time=60
```

this specified that `-1` is **unlimited** because no script can be executed with a negative time.

the value `0` means you don't allow your script to **parse data** or to **download files.**

Answer (score 0):

Basically `max_input_time = -1` means what you've said, there is no time limit for that directive.

Answer (score -2):

max_input_time = -1 as maximum value. It is 2147483647 in PHP 5.4